# Julia: Gtk windows do not display

Tags: gtk, julia

I have been working with the Gtk package in Julia. Yesterday everything was fine. Today, Gtk windows do not show up on my screen.

In the REPL:

```
using Gtk
win = Window("I am a window")
```

The lines are executed just fine, but nothing shows up. Calling "showall(win)" doesn't do anything. Here is the printout:

```
GtkWindow(name="", parent, width-request=-1, height-request=-1, visible=TRUE, sensitive=TRUE, app-paintable=FALSE, can-focus=FALSE, has-focus=FALSE, is-focus=FALSE, can-default=FALSE, has-default=FALSE, receives-default=FALSE, composite-child=FALSE, style, events=0, no-show-all=FALSE, has-tooltip=FALSE, tooltip-markup=NULL, tooltip-text=NULL, window, double-buffered=TRUE, halign=GTK_ALIGN_FILL, valign=GTK_ALIGN_FILL, margin-left=0, margin-right=0, margin-top=0, margin-bottom=0, margin=0, hexpand=FALSE, vexpand=FALSE, hexpand-set=FALSE, vexpand-set=FALSE, expand=FALSE, border-width=0, resize-mode=GTK_RESIZE_QUEUE, child, type=GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL, title="I am a window", role=NULL, resizable=TRUE, modal=FALSE, window-position=GTK_WIN_POS_NONE, default-width=-1, default-height=-1, destroy-with-parent=FALSE, hide-titlebar-when-maximized=FALSE, icon, icon-name=NULL, screen, type-hint=GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_NORMAL, skip-taskbar-hint=FALSE, skip-pager-hint=FALSE, urgency-hint=FALSE, accept-focus=TRUE, focus-on-map=TRUE, decorated=TRUE, deletable=TRUE, gravity=GDK_GRAVITY_NORTH_WEST, transient-for, attached-to, opacity=1.000000, has-resize-grip=TRUE, resize-grip-visible=TRUE, application, ubuntu-no-proxy=FALSE, is-active=FALSE, has-toplevel-focus=FALSE, startup-id, mnemonics-visible=FALSE, focus-visible=TRUE, )
```

I noticed this problem this morning. The only update that might have something to do with it is julia(0.3.0-1079~ubuntu12.04.1, 0.3.0-1088~ubuntu12.04.1).

Thank you

Comment: Try updating Gtk.jl (`Pkg.update()`). This may be due to https://github.com/JuliaLang/Gtk.jl/issues/81

Comment: Good point. It worked! I also notice that one must now use win = @GtkWindow()

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by:

1. updating the package with Pkg.update()
2. importing Gadfly alongside Cairo causes the draw function to get messed up. Just don't import Gadfly